# Referencing an object in multiple Tests

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I currently have an object that references cells in CSV file. My problem is when I create this object I cannot reference it in other tests without creating a new one. For example

```java
@Test(priority=14)
public void deleteClass() throws Exception{
  readingFromExcel excel = new readingFromExcel();
  String cell = excel.readingFromExcel("TestSheet",1,1);
  CreateClass.deleteClass(cell);
}

////@Test(priority=15)
public void deleteCategory() throws Exception{
  CreateCategory.deleteCategory(cell);
}
```

How can I create my object cell and refer to it in two tests?

Comment: I'd generally caution against class variables in tests simple because making a test require another test to run first will make your tests brittle.

Comment: Yes but one test is creating and the next test deletes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put the following outside any method body but inside the class (instance level variable):

```
String cell;
```

And inside the method body:

```
cell = excel.readingFromExcel("TestSheet",1,1);
```

And also make sure that first `deleteClass()` and then `deleteCategory()` is called when you run all the tests of this class.

Comment: This worked thank you why did this happen? Just for my own understanding.

Comment: When you write String cell = excel.readingFromExcel("TestSheet",1,1); inside the method body, scope of the variable named cell is limited to the containing method. This can not accessed from another method. By the way if think it's working why don't you accept the answer.